# Regex pattern for not allowing characters other than ALL , - and [0-9]

Tags: javascript, regex

We are trying to populate a Regex for the requirement mentioned in title, but we are not able to form multiple regex expression in a single pattern, so can someone please help me on this.

Comment: can you please add what you have done till now, and expected input/output please

Comment: text box should allow a combination like this ALL,01-08,01,05 so we are trying form a regex for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex :

```
/^(ALL|[\d,-]+)*$/
```

Maches :

- 123
- 123.45
- 123-45
- 123-45.67
- 123-45-67
- ALL
- ALL-123,65448
- 123,ALL-123,654-48

[<kbd>Try it</kbd>](http://regex101.com/r/gD5rC5/2)

**EDIT:**

After reading your last comments, I think you want to match a list of elements (ALL or [\d-]) separated by dashes. If it's right, this second regex will fit your needs :

```
/^((?:(?:ALL|[\d-]+)(?:$|,))+)/
```

[<kbd>Try it</kbd>](http://regex101.com/r/gD5rC5/4)

Answer (score 0):

A simple pattern like this:

```
[^0-9,-]
```

Should be enough if i understood the question.

Comment: text box should allow a combination like this - ALL,01-08,01,05